# What would be the best and worst time to ask questions on Physics Stack Exchange?

Tags: support

Perhaps somebody may know the time (of a specific timezone) where most people are online and offline.

Comment: Related question on main meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1313/209806 and links therein.

Comment: Slightly better link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213603/ and the data queries linked.

Comment: IMO, getting a *good answer* should trump getting a *fast* one; it is not always the case that the good answer is the fast one. So, as I see it, "best and worst times" are completely irrelevant.

Comment: It's not that just because a "less authorititative" user answers your question, a "more authoritative" user will not answer too. I feel that phrase is unnecessary in your question.

Comment: Hi Neil, from the comments, I would guess you have altered your post from its original, which I did not see. Sticking purely to the timezone part, I can only tell you my own experience is: 7pm GMT to 10 GMT is optimum for my questions to get noticed (if at all:)

Answer (score 4):

Well there's actually a [Data Query for that](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/352479/best-time-for-an-answer?MaxTimeDiff=1440)<sup>1</sup>. The results of which are seen below. The y-axis is the average time (in minutes) between the question posting and the answer posted, the x-axis is the day & hour binning of the week in [UTC time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)<sup>2</sup>

[image: Plot of mean time between question posted & answer given]

The top 8 days, hours & time difference for the shortest times between question posted and answer given (and for the last year) are:

```
  Day  |  Hour  |  Time difference
------------------------------------
  Sun  |  1300  |     78 min
  Sat  |  1700  |     83 min
  Tue  |  1600  |     86 min
  Thu  |  1200  |     88 min
  Mon  |  1400  |     91 min
  Mon  |  1300  |     91 min
  Sun  |  1100  |     91 min
  Fri  |  2000  |     92 min
```

The mean time across the week is **170 minutes** (or 2 hours, 50 minutes)

However, as I stated in a comment, ***quality*** answers are what you *should* be wanting, not *fastest* answers. In this case, you may be waiting some time (hours into days into weeks) for a *good* answer to your question.

<sup>1 I've modified [the original version](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/155028/best-time-to-ask-questions-on-stackexchange-get-answer-faster) to eliminate some, IMO, goofy options</sup>
<sup>2  Here is a handy [UTC Time Now calculator](http://time.unitarium.com/utc/) in case you don't know what your local time is in UTC.</sup>

Comment: Note to self: probably should update this since it's been nearly 5 years since posting & users have come & gone.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried to chart when questions usually get more views and answers or when answers of my own get more attention. It seems to have little to do with time. There are usually a fair number of users online at all times. There is a rise and fall in activity on the site and the rate of asked/answered/modified posts through the day, however I never could find a significant relationship between the time and the probability of a question getting a good answer or an answer getting a decent amount of attention.

During peak activity, there are more users, but posts become buried in the active page quicker. During the least active times, there are less users but posts stay on the active page longer. Not only this, but there are good answering users available all through the day. However, the best users to answer your question (based on the topic of the question) may or may not be online at any given time.

The point is that since it is a diurnal cycle of activity, after about a day (based on my observations and controlled for quality of the thread) you have about the same amount of activity for a question no matter when it was posted. Good questions will be upvoted, viewed, and answered. Bad questions will be downvoted, closed, and/or ignored. In all cases, you usually get 1 to 2 days of activity for a given question. Unless it's a HNQ, which can get *up to* a week extra on our site. After that, only editing the posts will get it a few more views (this is all for average posts. Posts at either ends of the curve will obviously be susceptible to irregular activity).

Comment: A teary eyed +1 for "_During peak activity, there are more users, but posts become buried in the active page quicker_". I've tasted just that with [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/137163/simultanously-hot-and-dense-in-qcd) old question of mine. I had roughly estimated when the activity is highest, and then posted, so that it gets more attention. Didn't work out. Plus, it got buried so deep that it has managed all of 48 views in 10 months, let alone a satisfactory answer :(

Comment: @TheDarkSide Alas, that is the problem. That's why some of my best answers have gotten no or almost no votes. There are time of the year when this is worse though. The start and end of school terms buries posts so quickly that it's almost not worth it to post at all