# Are there certain times of day that are best for posting Questions and Answers on Physics Stack Exchange as of late 2019?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-statistics

I was wondering if there are certain times of day, and of the week that questions are most likely to get the most high quality answers on Physics Stack Exchange accounting for the questions asked, and when looking to answer questions if there are times that are most likely to have questions that have yet to be answered.

Comment: I don't know statistically but I believe that whatever the answer may be would get into a feedback loop as people would start posting questions on that time only and hence you see It can be any day of the week. Let it be Sunday.

Comment: Define "high quality". If you're happy to accept a proxy measure (score, or something similar), then it can probably be obtained from [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com). If you have something specific you'd like to see out of that data, and you're having trouble writing a good query, let me know.

Comment: Related, if not dupe of, https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6968/25301

Comment: @EmilioPisanty when I say good quality answers I mean answers that are most likely to contain accurate information, while also taking into account the level of knowledge of the one asking the question.

Comment: @AndersGustafson That's a subjective statement, and one which can only be checked by hand. Putting those two together, if you want an answer in those terms, there is no other way to answer your question other than for you to go by hand through a representative sample of questions and rate their answers' quality.